# Error in importing twitter data: "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3258 (char 3257)"

Tags: python, json, twitter, import

I'm trying to obtain some data on twitter with the following code:

```
import os
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import json

access_token = "wwwwwww"
access_token_secret = "xxxxxxxx"
consumer_key = "yyyyyyyyy"
consumer_secret = "zzzzzzzz"

# Pass OAuth details to tweepy's OAuth handler
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

tweet_list = []

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        super(MyStreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.file = open("tweets.txt", "w")
    def on_status(self, status):
        tweet = status._json
        self.file.write(json.dumps(tweet) + '\\n')
        tweet_list.append(status)
        self.num_tweets += 1
        if self.num_tweets < 100:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        self.file.close()

# Initialize Stream listener
l = MyStreamListener()

# Create your Stream object with authentication
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)

# Filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords:
stream.filter(track= ('clinton', 'trump', 'sanders', 'cruz'))

# String of path to file: tweets_data_path
tweets_data_path = "tweets.txt"

# Initialize empty list to store tweets: tweets_data
tweets_data = []

# Open connection to file
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

# Read in tweets and store in list: tweets_data
for line in tweets_file:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)

# Close connection to file
tweets_file.close()

# Print the keys of the first tweet dict
print(tweets_data[0].keys())
```

But when I run my project, the output is the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/servo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/tweeter.py", line 53, in <module>
    tweet = json.loads(line)
  File "C:\Users\servo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\servo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3258 (char 3257)
```

I have done some research about handling this, even on documentation and other StackOverflow topics, but I didn't find anything that could help.

Comment: could you please provide a minimal example that doesn't require a twitter account? e.g. provide the json response as a string?

Comment: @mrxra, how can I do that? Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: according to your stacktrace, the issue seems to be here ```tweet = json.loads(line)```. what is the content of ```tweets_file``` (tweets.txt) when you reach that line of code (after your stream listener supposedly dumped some json into it) ?

Comment: @mrxra, this is the content of tweets file:
tweets_file
Out[4]: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='tweets.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

and this is (part of) the content of twitter.txt:
{"created_at": "Wed Aug 05 00:56:54 +0000 2020", "id": 1290814001421713409, "id_str": "1290814001421713409", "text": "@bvckfromthedead Weil ein Nachmacher nicht mit den echten g\u2018s chillt", "display_text_range": [17, 68], "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", "truncated": false, "in_reply_to_status_id": 1290779856976977920, "in_reply_to_status_"